# How to make second autocomplete options dependent on first autocomplete selection using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, dependencies, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a form with a text input and select option box.  The text field uses an autosuggest to allow users to pick options from a list.  Once a a value is selected from the autosuggest, the select option box is populated with options dependent on the selection.

I am working to change the code over so that the second box is a text input as well, so as not to limit the users choices (i.e. both fields should allow free text entries if the user does not want to select from the available choices).

I think I've stared at this code too long, and would love some help.  Clearly the changes need to come in the `loadCountry`, `populateSelect` and `loadcountrySelect` functions.

I am using PHP, jQuery and [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

Any help you could provide would be very much appreciated!

Scripts:

```
<script src="../../scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script src="../../scripts/jqueryui/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="../../scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="../../scripts/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script src="../../scripts/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    function ord(chr) {

        return chr.charCodeAt(0);

    }

    function chr(num) {

        return  String.fromCharCode(num);

    }

    function quote(str) {

        return '"' + escape(str.replace('"', "'")) + '"';

    }

    String.prototype.titleCase = function () {

        var chars = [" ", "-"];
        var ths = String(this).toLowerCase();

        for (j in chars){

            var car = chars[j];
            var str = "";
            var words = ths.split(car);
            for(i in words){

                str += car + words[i].substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + words[i].substr(1);

            }

            ths = str.substr(1);

        }

        return ths;

    }

    function incrementTerm(term) {

        for (var i = term.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){

            var code = term.charCodeAt(i);

            if (code < ord('Z'))

                return term.substring(0, i) + chr(code + 1);

        }

        return '{}'

    }

    function parseLineSeperated(data){

        data = data.split("\n");

        data.pop(); // Trim blank element after ending newline

        var out = []

        for (i in data){

            out.push(data[i].titleCase());

        }

        return out;

    }

    function guess(value){

        var oldValue = $('.continent_autocomplete').val();

        if (oldValue == value)

            return;

        $('.continent_autocomplete').val(value);

        $('.continent_autocomplete').caret(oldValue.length, value.length);

    }

    function clearGuess(){

        var field = $('.continent_autocomplete');

        field.val(field.val().substring(0, field.caret().start));

    }

    function loadcontinent(request, response) {

        var startTerm = request.term.toUpperCase();

        var endTerm = incrementTerm(startTerm);

        $.ajax({

            url: '/db/continent.php?startkey='+startTerm+'&endkey='+endTerm,

            success: function(data) {

                var items = parseLineSeperated(data);

                response(items);

            },

            error: function(req, str, exc) {

                alert(str);

            }

            });

    }

    function loadcountry(handler) {

        var continent = $('.continent_autocomplete').val().toUpperCase();


        $.ajax({

            url: '/db/country.php?key=' + continent,

            success: function(data) {

                handler(parseLineSeperated(data));

            },

            error: function(req, str, exc) {

                alert(str);

            }

            });

    }

    function populateSelect(select, options) {

        select.html('');

        if (options.length) {

            enableSelect();

            for (i in options){

                var option = options[i];

                select.append($('<option></option>').val(option).html(option));

            }

        } else {

            disableSelect('Country');

        }

    }

    function loadcountrySelect(continentObj){

        disableSelect('Loading...');

        loadcountry(function(options){

            populateSelect($('.country_autocomplete'), options);

        });

    }

    function disableSelect(message){

        var select = $('.country_autocomplete');

        select.html("<option>" + message + "</option>");

        select.attr('disabled', true);

    }

    function enableSelect(){

        var select = $('.country_autocomplete');

        select.attr('disabled', false);

    }

    populateSelect($(".country_autocomplete"), []);

    $("input.continent_autocomplete").autocomplete({

        source: loadcontinent,

        select: function(event, ui){

            $("input.continent_autocomplete").val(ui.item.value);

            loadcountrySelect(event.target);

        }

    });


    $("input.continent_autocomplete").keyup(function (event){

        var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

        if (code == 8) { // Backspace

            clearGuess();

        }

        event.target.value = event.target.value.titleCase();

        loadcountrySelect(event.target);

    });
});

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="continent_name">
    <label> Continent Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="continent_name" name="continent_name" class="continent_autocomplete" />
</div>
<div id="country">
    <label> Country:</label>
    <input type="text" id="country_autocomplete" name="country_autocomplete" class="country_autocomplete" />
</div>
```

continent.php

```
<?php

$db_host        = 'XXX';
$db_user        = 'XXX';
$db_password    = 'XXX';
$db_name        = 'XXX';

$db = new mysqli($db_host , $db_user ,$db_password, $db_name);

if(!$db) {

    echo 'There was a problem connecting to the database';
} else {

    if(isset($_GET['startkey'])) {
        $mysearchString = $db->real_escape_string($_GET['startkey']);


        if(strlen($mysearchString) >0) {


            $query = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCTROW Continent 
                                FROM locations 
                                WHERE Continent 
                                LIKE '$mysearchString%' 
                                LIMIT 10"); 

            if($query) {

                while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {

                        print ucwords(strtolower($result->Continent))."\n";
                }

            } else {

                echo 'ERROR: There was a problem with the query.';
            }

        } else {

        } 

    } else {

        echo 'Access denied.';
    }
}
?>
```

country.php

```
<?php
$db_host        = 'XXX';
$db_user        = 'XXX';
$db_password    = 'XXX';
$db_name        = 'XXX';

$db = new mysqli($db_host , $db_user ,$db_password, $db_name);

if(!$db) {

    echo 'There was a problem connecting to the database';

} else {

    if(isset($_GET['key'])) {

        $mysearchString = $db->real_escape_string($_GET['key']);

        if(strlen($mysearchString) >0) {

            $query = $db->query("SELECT Continent,Country,Abbrev 
                                 FROM locations 
                                 WHERE Continent 
                                 LIKE '$mysearchString%' 
                                 ORDER BY Country
                                 LIMIT 20");    

            if($query) {

                while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {

                    print ucwords(strtolower($result->Country))."/".
                          ucwords(strtolower(strtok($result->Abbrev,";")))."\n";

                }

            } else {

                echo 'ERROR: There was a problem with the query.';

            }

        } else {

        } 

    } else {

        echo 'Access denied.';

    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Does `country.php` take a parameter to filter searches? If so, what is it?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker just added the code for continent.php and country.php above.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to modify your PHP to get this to work optimally (filtering occurring on the server). I would update your PHP so that it queries your database with two parameters (one for country, one for continent):

```
$continent = $db->real_escape_string($_GET['continent']);
$country = $db->real_escape_string($_GET['country']);

$query = $db->query("SELECT Continent,Country,Abbrev 
    FROM locations 
    WHERE Continent ='$continent' and Country like '$country%'
    ORDER BY Country
    LIMIT 20");
```

*(Please take with a grain of salt; I don't know PHP)*

Basically, pass a continent (which was selected in the first `input`) *along with* the country search string (which was typed in the second input).

Next, you're going to need to apply the autocomplete widget to the second `input`. Something like:

```
$("#country_autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var continent = $("#continent_autocomplete").val()
            , country = request.term;

        $.ajax({
            url: '/db/country.php?continent=' + continent + "&country=" + country,
            success: function(data) {
                response(parseLineSeperated(data));
            },
            error: function(req, str, exc) {
                alert(str);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Just for some polish, you'll probably want to clear `#country_autocomplete` when `#continent_autocomplete` changes. You can do that by adding an event handler for autocomplete's `change` event:

```
$("input.continent_autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: loadcontinent,
    change: function () {
        $("#country_autocomplete).val('');
    }
});
```

Lastly, you'll want to remove any code that has to do with populating the country `select`, since you no longer need it.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery plugin [Autocomplete like Google](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/autocomplete/#visibleLimit) supports such functionality:

**autocomplete.php** (agly style, the whole logic at one place -- just to show the principle)

```
if(!empty($_GET['foo_name']) && !empty($_GET['bar_number'])) {
    $sql = 'SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE';
    $db = new MySQLi(...);
    $db->query($sql);
    $numbers = [];
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $numbers[] = $row['bar_number'];
    }
}
echo json_encode($numbers);
```

**autocomplete.html**

```
<link href="/components/autocompletelikegoogle/jquery.autocomplete.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/components/autocompletelikegoogle/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/autocomplete.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="foo_name" id="foo-name" value="">
<input type="text" name="bar_number" id="bar-number" value="">
```

**autocomplete.js**

```
$(function() {
    $("#foo").autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        limit: 5,
        source : [{
            url:"/my/ajax/controller/foo?data[foo_name]=%QUERY%",
            type:'remote'
        }],  
    });
});

$(function() {
    $("#bar").autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        limit: 5,
        appendMethod:'replace',
        source : [
            function(query, add) {
                fooName = $('#foo-name').val();
                $.getJSON("/my/ajax/controller/bar?data[bar_number]=" + query + "&data[foo_name]=" + fooName, function(response) {
                    add(response);
                })
        }],  
    });
});
```